# scala neat way to match and map out Iterable

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am still learning to code in Scala/Spark and I have a problem and greatly appreciate your help.

I have an Iterable with a Key and a Double.

The Iterable [Key] is a subset of say 5 possible Keys say:

```
population
age
gender
height
weight
```

and the Double is the corresponding reading.

My question is that I want to represent my data in a flat format of:

```
(Double,Double,Double,Double,Double)
```

which corresponds to the readings from Keys in specific order:

```
(population,age,gender,height,weight)
```

but in the Iterable where a key does not exist, I want still need to pad it with a 0. So for example:

```
Iterable((population,10),(age,21),(gender,0))
```

I want to be able to represent this as

```
(10,21,0,0,0) //the last 2 zeros are padded because there is no key matching height and weight.
```

So far I've been doing individual match to each key (if exist then copy the Double and if not pad with zero), but I want to know if there is a neat way of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd create a `Map`. So say you've got your `Iterable`:

```
val values = Seq(("population", 10), ("age", 21), ("gender", 0)).toIterable
```

Convert it to a map:

```
val keyValueMap = values.toMap
```

And when you extract the values from it, just use the `getOrElse` function:

```
keyValueMap.getOrElse("height", defaultHeight)
```

Comment: Cool, this is much neater than my current method.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do is first define the order of the elements, so,

`val keyOrder = List("population", "age", "gender", "height", "weight")`

Next, you can just do something like;

```
val valMap = Map("population" -> 199D, "gender" -> 1D, "weight" -> 50D)

keyOrder.map(k => valMap.getOrElse(k, 0D))
```

Comment: Cool, this is also very neat, do you mind explaining to me what the D is doing?

Comment: The D makes sure that the integer value is interpreted as a double